# Select most recent transactions pr item

Tags: sql-server

On a Microsoft SQL database, I am looking for at way to find the most recent salesdate and customer pr item.
If two customers has bought the same item, i just want one of the customers.

Every item should only apear once in my query.

Here is an example of my data:

```
Rownumber   Item    Customer        Date        QTY
1           10      2000            01/01/2014  5   
2           10      3000            02/01/2014  6
3           10      2000            02/01/2014  4   
4           20      4000            10/01/2014  1
5           20      4000            01/01/2014  8   
6           30      5000            08/01/2014  5
7           40      2000            07/01/2014  10
```

My result should be somthing like

```
2           10      3000            02/01/2014  6
4           20      4000            10/01/2014  1
6           30      5000            08/01/2014  5
7           40      2000            07/01/2014  10
```

Instead of row 2, it could be row three, because they are on the same date. I just need one of them.

I will guess it is some RANK function, but i cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1):

**Using CTE**

```
;WITH Latest
AS
 (
  SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
  FROM TABLE
 )
SELECT * FROM Latest
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Using Sub-Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
  FROM TABLE
)Q
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Also change the ORDER BY section of the ROW_NUMBER() to `ORDER BY [Date] Desc, RowNumber DESC` to ensure you get the most recent transaction for that date, if more than one transaction exists on that date. If you want a row per each customer AND item, the change the PARTITION BY section to `PARTITION BY Customer, Item`.